# Why my html file is not displayed in android application?

Tags: android

When I build and run the application I see only black screen,The html file is using java script,video,audio file and images,I used these codes

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/aici/index.html");
}
```

Comment: Did you declare Internet permission in Manifest?

Comment: yes I did <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: the thing is on pc the html file didn't worked on opera just on internet explorer..now I don't know what browser its using to open it..and how to change it

Comment: Did you add the index.html file in assets folder? might be it is your path issue

Comment: app>src>main>assets>aici>index.html but I think isn't a path issue since I have a black screen instead of all items displayed,or error "item not found"

Comment: Can you please add your html file/? , https://paste.ofcode.org/

Comment: <html>
    <head>
  <title>Brave Code Test</title>
  <script src="javascript/pixi.dev.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <script src="javascript/base.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>  I have no clue how to add link..it doesn't work []() format